# Why last row deleted when refresh page

Tags: wp-query, database, mysql

when I refresh page table row deleted and last query deleted when I click on any delete button of other row. Why is this happened?

this is table which I displayed

```
                <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $table= 'wp_contact_form';
                $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $table" );

                if(!empty($result)){

                foreach ( $result as $print ) {  
                        
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $print->id;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->names;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->emails;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->gender;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->age;?></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" id="" name="update"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="delete" id="delete" name="delete"></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                } 
                ?>
```

this is delete query

```
                   $id= $print->id;
                   if(isset($_POST['delete']))
                    {
                      $result = $wpdb->delete($table, array('id' => $id));
                    if(!empty($result))
                       {
                        echo "success";
                       }
                    }
```

error screenshot - https://prnt.sc/wdg3xv

Comment: `$_POST` data is often re-sent when you refresh the page, and you code doesn't do anything to specify which post is deleted. It just uses the last value of `$print` in your loop.

Comment: Okay, I got it. It gets last id, so what change should I do?

Comment: You need to build a form around your buttons which passes data to the query - this could be with AJAX or on page load - as the moment, those buttons are doing nothing.

Comment: no, I made buttons in the form

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the error is you are not creating a form for it, so the last result being used in the foreach is assigning that $print->id to $id.

If you did this

```
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <form method="POST"  action="{page url}">
    <td><?php echo $print->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->names; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->emails; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->gender; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->age; ?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" id="" name="update"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="delete" id="delete" name="delete"></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $print->id; ?>"/></form>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

When testing I had to enter the page url into the  tags as described with {page url} because my page function set it as `admin.php?page=test` so in mine it looked like this `<form method="POST"  action="?page=test">`

That creates a form with an extra post with the id.

Then the delete function looks like this

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $result = $wpdb->delete($table, array('id' => $id));
    if(!empty($result))
        {
            echo "success";
        }
}
```